# How to only Search for Exact Value in CSV Python 2.7?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I am using pandas and numpy to search my CSV files, the problem is that, for example, if i'm searching for 'foo' and the value is 'foo1' it will still return true. How can I only search for 'foo' and nothing else? I am searching the specific row, but the value will occasionally just get a number added to the end of it, like 'foo' will change to 'foo1' or 'foo2' and I can't really change that. Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv')
x = np.where((df['Name'] == name) & (df['Num'] == 'foo'))
try:
    if (x[0][0] + 1) > 0: #also if someone has a better method
        return True       #for returning True please let me know
except IndexError:
    return False
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're "searching the specific row"?  What kind of output do you want?

Comment: Show us a sample of the `df['Num']` column, and indicate which items you want to find.  Do you want to keep or exclude lines where `df['Num']=='foo1'`.  Also I don't understand the purpose of that `x[0][0]` test.

Comment: @hpaulj I am trying to search a csv for a name and check if their Num is the same as it was the last time they ran the script. If it is the same I want to return True, and if it changed I want to return False. But if the Num is changed to 'foo1' It still returns True, despite it being changed. For the x[0][0] test, I am just using this as a way to see if x was found. it gives me the row # in an array, and [0][0] gives me the row # as a str, and then I add one because it doesn't account for the header row. I'm sure there's an easier way, but idk of one.

Answer (score 1):

To find `foo` and `foo` only you may do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["foo","bar","foobar"]})
df
    a
0   foo
1   bar
2   foobar

df["a"].str.contains("^foo$")
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @Ecom1414 Why not accept answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution would work, only `np.where` is necessary omit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num':['foo', 'foo1', 'foow'], 'Name':['name1','name1','name3']})

print (df)
    Name   Num
0  name1   foo
1  name1  foo1
2  name3  foow

name = 'name1'
mask = (df['Name'] == name) & (df['Num'] == 'foo')
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

If need scalar output add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True`:

```
val = ((df['Name'] == name) & (df['Num'] == 'foo')).any()
print (val)
True
```

Or if need check all values if `True` add [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num':['foo', 'foo'], 'Name':['name1','name1']})

print (df)
    Name  Num
0  name1  foo
1  name1  foo

name = 'name1'
val = ((df['Name'] == name) & (df['Num'] == 'foo')).all()
print (val)
True
```